Java use a custom annotation to trigger a method call from @PreAuthorize
I have a controller with an endpoint I need to authorize.
I want to use a custom annotation which contains @PreAuthorize annotation.
This is my controller
@RestController
public class ActorController {
    @GetMapping("policyPoc")
    @UsePolicyEvaluator(value = "xxxxxx")
    public Mono<String> policyPoc() {
        return Mono.just("running policyPoc");
    }

This is my annotation:
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("@policyEvaluator.hasPermission(#value)")
public @interface UsePolicyEvaluator {
    String value() default "";
}

This is the evaluator code:
@Component(value="policyEvaluator")
public class PolicyEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public boolean hasPermission(String value) {
        log.info(value)
        return true;
    }

When I run the code I keep getting null for the field value in hasPermission method.
Any ideas why I cannot transfer the value using the custom annotation?
Thanks
I tried changing the parameters names, and also remove the annotation.
When adding @PreAuthorize("@policyEvaluator.hasPermission(#value)") to the endpoint, the value does appear to get to hasPermission correctly.
